# Can I connect a heartbeat sensor to XBee?

Tags: sensors, xbee, heartbeat, analog-digital-converter, node-xbee

Can I connect the heartbeat rate sensor XD-58C to the analog pin of an XBee and send this value to a base station (PC) that have XBee connected to it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect the heart beat sensor as Xbee has analog pins and digital pins. You can set these pins in the XCTU software. Then you have to read the serial send from xbee that is connected to the heart beat sensor to the coordinator xbee. Analog data will use packet in 20 and 21 iterations.

Comment: what you mean in Analog data will use packet in 20 and 21 iterations.??

Comment: You can further check on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnBx2yqKn_E    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzH146rR-7I&t=236s